# Placing a rectangle on a 3D triangle

Tags: geometry

### Background

> [image]

I have a 3D triangle (let's call the points **XYZ**) and trying to place a rectangle on it. By that I mean the points of the rectangle should stick to the surface of the triangle in 3D space. The position and size of the rectangle should be defined by some offset vectors relative to **X**.

### My Understanding

My approach would be to calculate two normalized vectors, one which points from **X** to **Y** and the other one which is rectangular to the first one and points to the direction of **Z**. By multiplicating some offset's with the two unit vectors it should be possible to calculate **ABCD** on the surface of the triangle.

Could that work? How can I calculate this unit vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot product of $\vec{XZ}$ with the unit vector $\vec{XY} / \left| \vec{XY} \right|$ gives you the projection
of $\vec{XZ}$ onto $\vec{XY} $.
That multiplied by the unit vector $\vec{XY} / \left| \vec{XY} \right|$ itself is the component along it of $\vec{XZ}$.
$\vec{XZ}$ minus the last  is the orthogonal component you are looking for.
Make it unitary, ...